# Changing Java API to make xxx.out.println to work the same way as system.out.println

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, customization

I need to change the java API to make say assassinscreed.out.println to work the same way as system.out.println..

Can u pls shed some light on it..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple.

In the class `assassinscreed`, add the following declaration:

```
 public static final PrintStream out = System.out;
```

Implementing the equivalent of the `System.setOut()` method is tricky.  You could use reflection to update the value of the `out` "constant".  However, there's a risk that some code will see stale copies of the reference.  And I don't think the JLS provides a way to mitigate that ... because from the JLS perspective the value is not supposed to change.

So if you need to change the value of `out` on the fly, this is not the right solution.  In fact, I'd say that it is not the right solution at all.  It would be better to write this as:

```
private static PrintStream out = System.out;
public static PrintStream getOut() {
    returns out;
}
```

... with a setter if you need one.

(In my opinion, the classic design was a big mistake.  It certainly made it a lot harder to implement light-weight applications within a JVM.)

---

(And don't ever use "assassinscreed" as a class name.  Stick to the standard Java class naming conventions!)

Answer (score 0):

Assign assassinscreed.out to the same value as System.out.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
 BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new
                FileOutputStream(java.io.FileDescriptor.out), "ASCII"), 512);
 out.write("Hello World");
 out.flush();
```